# Embed Javascript in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I need way to add javascript code in VB.NET;

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://example.com/api.php?p=mail';})();")
```

I use this javascript code to fill form in website (On Firefox Browser with Bookmarks)

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://example.com/api.php?p=mail
```

Now I want use it in VB.Net Browser but when I do Invoke Script nothing happens. I also tried on other ways but don't go.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
> WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://example.com/api.php?p=mail';})();", "JScript"
> ```

See [VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?317502-How-can-you-execute-javascript-in-a-webbrowser)...